# Least stressful way to check a git repo's heads using the git CLI tool

Tags: git

What's the least stressful way to poke a git server for a listing of all the repo's head commits?

More specifically, I'll be doing this a lot to a lot of git repos, so optimizing the query time is extremely important so as to not nuke the servers.

This should be obvious, but: cloning is not an option.

(In the future, this will be done a lot more efficiently, but right now I just need a proof of concept for my federated *thing*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git provides an `ls-remote` command that you can use. For example:

```
$ git ls-remote https://github.com/git/git.git
041f5ea1cf987a4068ef5f39ba0a09be85952064        HEAD
aeb582a98374c094361cba1bd756dc6307432c42        refs/heads/maint
041f5ea1cf987a4068ef5f39ba0a09be85952064        refs/heads/master
f8f6787159eebeb0fe8766e114123185ee1893ea        refs/heads/next
55070086a7b72850cce2e7e1688deb53114aac65        refs/heads/pu
be6eed6d9f1c0dfa4a732832c506318f916caf09        refs/heads/todo
f0d0fd3a5985d5e588da1e1d11c85fba0ae132f8        refs/pull/10/head
[...]
```

This is the cheapest option you can use, but be aware that most hosting providers will rate-limit you regardless. Your tools should learn how to back off if they're doing automated processing of repositories.

You can also make queries directly to the `/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack` part of the URL, which is essentially equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

What if you clone, but not checkout any of the files?

1. Make a new folder
2. Run a `git init` to initialize it as a git repository
3. Run `git clone -n [git://path/to/repo.git]`

This will make a new folder "repo" inside of your new folder, with none of the repo's files, only it's .git/ folder. Then you can take a look at whatever you need to.

Still painful and you said no cloning but this will work.

Comment: This is still a clone and as such is quite expensive as it retrieves all the commits/objects. I'm trying to avoid remote server load.